# How to get last record position without array formula in Excel-2007 based on condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find last record position of particular item in a column without array approach.
[image]

```
Org
---
Exim
Exim
Agrani
BCBL
Rupali
DSE
NCC
NRBCB
UTTARA
Exim
Rupali
BDBL
BCBL
```

With the following array formula I can get it. Is there any non array formula got achieve same? I know several option is available on excel latest versions but my limitation is only on `Excel-2007`.

```
=LARGE(IF(B3:B15=D5,ROW(B3:B15)-ROW(B2),""),1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
'for xl2007 as standard formula
=MAX(INDEX(ROW(1:13)-(B3:B15<>D5)*1E+99, , ))

'for xl2007 as array formula with CSE
=large(if(b3:b15=d5, row(1:13)), 1)

'for xl2010 and later as standard formula
=aggregate(14, 6, row(1:13)/(b3:b15=d5), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: `=MAX(INDEX(ROW(1:13)-(B3:B15<>D5)*1E+99, , ))` this formula works for me. Can you please explain `*1E+99` how it working?

Comment: 1E+99 is a 1 followed by 99 zeroes. Any position number that does not have a match has 1e99 subtracted from it and those will not be the max of anything. The matching positions remain the same and max takes the largest.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explanation.