# How to filter data based on condition using non array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following sample data  and want to auto filter them based on `status` condition `Complete` using formula only. I know how to filter using `array formula` and `VBA` custom function. Right now I am filtering it using following array formula. Due to some limitation, I want to ignore `VBA` and `array` formula. Is there any function combination to achieve it as non-array formula?

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$E$13,SMALL(IF($E$4:$E$13="Complete",ROW($E$4:$E$13)-ROW($E$3)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")}
```

============================= ***Sample Data*** =================================

```
   ID   User    Task                 Status
----------------------------------------------
Emp-001 Harun   Prepare Document    Complete
Emp-002 Rahim   Print               Complete
Emp-003 Karim   Binding             Progress
Emp-004 Jadhu   Packaging           Complete
Emp-005 Madhu   Prepare Document    Hold
Emp-006 Rahima  Print               Progress
Emp-007 Shila   Binding             Hold
Emp-008 Kaniz   Packaging           Complete
Emp-009 Jamila  Prepare Document    Progress
Emp-010 Rina    Print               Complete
```

***Screenshot:***
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve your goal if you are willing to use a "helper" column in column **K**

Comment: @pnuts I used `Advanced Filter` and can achieve it but `Advance Filter` needs manually triggering. If I can use formulas only then it will filter automatically when I put new data or change status when an user's task is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula in `G3` cell then drag and drop to down and right as needed. Hope this will help you.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$E$12,SMALL(INDEX(ROW($A$1:$A$10)-($E$3:$E$12<>"Complete")*(1E+99)*-1,, ),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

**Snapshot:**
[image]

Comment: Wow! the formula works like magic. It helps me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: Basically I get the idea from Jeeps answer to one of my question. [Link of that question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505886/how-to-get-last-record-position-without-array-formula-in-excel-2007-based-on-con)

Answer (score 0):

In **K4** enter:

```
=MATCH("Complete",E:E,0)
```

In **K5** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("complete",INDEX(E:E,K4+1):INDEX(E:E,9999),0)+K4,"")
```

and copy downward.  Column **K** defines the rows of interest.

In **G4** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,$K4),"")
```

copy this both across and downward:

[image]

Comment: It also works but better solution is without helper column. Thank for your answer.

Comment: @RainyDay  I agree completely!  I will use harun's method in the future!