# Vlookup to return multiple values for one User ID

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have quite a large amount of User IDs, around 30k or so. On one spreadsheet I have all of the User IDs paired with other relevant data related to the users. On another spreadsheet I have a larger list of User IDs (some repeated) with  other columns of data relating to the user IDs. 
What I would like to be able to do is to take a singular large column from one of the sheets and add it to the other using a Vlookup (or formula) and the User ID as the link between the two sheets. My issue is that the first match is being returned when I would like each individual match instead of just the first.

Thank you for any help or advice in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if `multiple unique values` is an oxymoron - but regardless, multiple matches will **not** cause an error with VLookUp -- it would just return the first match.  **Please [edit] your question to add the formula you're having trouble with.**  It's hard to say without seeing an example representative of the actual data, but I suspect a Pivot Tables would do this for you faster and easier.

Comment: It's just that I need each individual value instead of the first value to be matched with the users id.

Comment: It is possible to return all the information related one user ID. You can use a helper column for better performance. Array formulas also will do this but poor performance. Al there are some tricks to do this using some regular formula together.

Answer (score 1):

How would want to combine several matches into one cell?

I suggest to go the other way around - add the other columns to the spreadsheet with the repeated IDs.

Comment: I already have the User IDs entered the same number of times in the first sheet as the second sheet but the problem is when I try and match the value associated with the 2nd instance of User ID 1 to the 2nd instance of User ID 1 using vlookup, the 1st value associated with the 1st instance of User ID 1 is matched with the 2nd instance of user ID 1 when I want the 2nd value.

Comment: @Niall [Please see this post to filter data based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967385/how-to-filter-data-based-on-condition-using-non-array-formula). In this way your requirement may fulfill.

Comment: @ Niall (ANSWER FIXED) | 
VLookup only returns the first encounter.
My solution: 
In both spreadsheets, add another column (i.e 'F'), with '=countif($A2,$A$1:$A2)' - this will give you a serial number for each occurrence. Then add another column, combining the ID with its occurrence '=A2&F2'.
Then use the new column as the unique ID for your VLookup.

Comment: I switched the order of range and criteria - wasn't next to the program when I wrote it - the correct formula is '=COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,$A2)'